# Create Symfony Bundle for rest API

Tags: rest, api, symfony, routes, symfony-2.3

I'm working on symfony 3 project , I have a bundle for Admin dashboard and I want to create another bundle for a rest API , the main route for the dashboard is : *evaluation.dev/app_dev.php/* , for the API bundle i defined a route with fosrestBundle like that : *evaluation.dev/app_dev.php/api/* .

The route for the api work well but the main rout for my admin panel does not work anymore and show me an internal server error. can any one give some help ? I think I should change some thing on the configuration or routing file.

This is my routing.yml file :

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"

eval:
    resource: "@EvalBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation

api:
    resource: "@APIBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /api
```

here is my config.yml file :

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@EvalBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
    - { resource: "@EvalBundle/Resources/config/entities.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~

framework:
    #esi: ~
    #translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true
    translator: ~
    serializer:
        enabled: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    cache:  false
    form_themes :
        - bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig
        - bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        mapping_types:
            enum: string


        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/data/data.sqlite"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: EvalBundle\Entity\Collaborator
    from_email:
        address: amer.ff19@gmail.com
        sender_name: amer ff

knp_paginator:
    page_range: 1                      # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name: page                # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name: sort          # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name: direction # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct: true                 # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: 'KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig'     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: 'KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig' # sort link template

fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        include_format: false
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: 'json' }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: when I want to access to the main route evaluation.dev/app_dev.php/ I got this error : {"error":{"code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error","exception":[{"message":"Impossible to access an attribute (\"username\") on a null variable.","class":"Twig_Error_Runtime","trace": i if evaluation.dev/app_dev.php/login a html code appear but the evaluation.dev/app_dev.php/api/users work well and return a json response for all users from an active directory server !